# How to move blue box above the red and blue box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
body {
      background-color:olive;
      margin:0;
    }


    nav {
      background-color:aqua;
      position:sticky;
      top:0;
      border:1px solid red;

    }
    
    #container{
      max-height:1800px;
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:row;

      
    }

     a {
      
      background-color:chocolate;
      padding:7px;
      border-radius:10px; 
      text-decoration:none;
    }

    #container > a:hover{
      opacity:0.5;
    }

    

    #logout {
     margin-left:auto;
    }

    .bonus {
       margin-left:10px;
     }
    /* nav is finally done after 1.5 hours lol and another 30mins  */


    hr {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }


    .peepee{
      text-align:center;
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto;
      width:70%;
    }
    .bees {

      width:200px;
      float:right;
    }

    .flex-box {
     
      height:800px;
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      flex-wrap:wrap;
      
    }

    .flex-box > div {
      height:400px;
      width:300px;
    }
    .one{
      background-color:red;
    }

    .two {
      background-color:green; 
    }

    h1 {
      text-align:center;
      color:yellow;
    }

     li {
      font-weight:bold;
      line-height:40px;
    }

    .head {
      background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
<body>

  <img src=https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531870972494-627796a756dc?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=72a43beae93d56392f98f6eda2cdd8cb&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 width="100%" height="150" "border-radius:40px">
<nav>
  <div id="main-content">
  <div id="container" >
    <a id="main" href="main1.html">Main</a>
    <a id="information" class="bonus" href="information.html" style="background-color:#bad455">Statistics</a>
    <a id="contacts" class="bonus" href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
    <a id="media" class="bonus" href="media.html">Media</a>
    <a id="logout" href="logout.html">Log out</a>
    
</div>
  </div>
</nav>



    <p class="peepee"> <img class="bees" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Storni_1000128.JPG/1280px-Storni_1000128.JPG">More than 99 percent of all species, amounting to over five billion species,[7] that ever lived on Earth are estimated to be extinct.[8][9] Estimates on the number of Earth's current species range from 10 million to 14 million,[10] of which about 1.2 million have been documented and over 86 percent have not yet been described.[11] According to another study, the number of described species has been estimated at 1,899,587.[12] 2000–2009 saw approximately 17,000 species described per year.[12] The total number of undescribed organisms is unknown, but marine microbial species alone could number 20,000,000.[12] The number of quantified species will ipso facto always lag behind the number of described species, and species contained in these lists tend to be on the K side of the r/K selection continuum. More recently, in May 2016, scientists reported that 1 trillion species are estimated to be on Earth currently with only one-thousandth of one percent described.[13] The total amount of related DNA base pairs on Earth is estimated at 5.0 x 1037 and weighs 50 billion tonnes.[14] In comparison, the total mass of the biosphere has been estimated to be as much as 4 TtC (trillion [million million] tonnes of carbon).[15] In July 2016, scientists reported identifying a set of 355 genes from the Last Universal Common Ancestor (LUCA) of all organisms living on Earth.[16]</p>
   
 <hr>
   <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="head"></div>
     <div class="one">
      <h1>Pros</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Forest fires help to kill disease. </li>
        <li>It provides nutrients for new generations of growth. </li>
        <li>It refreshes the habitat zones. </li>
        <li>Low intensity fires don’t usually harm trees. </li>
      </ul>

     </div>
     <div class="two">
       <h1>Cons</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>A forest fire sets up the potential for soil erosion to occur. </li>
        <li>Forest fires always bring death in some form. </li>
        <li>Uncontrolled fires can cause localized air pollution. </li>
        <li>Homes can be destroyed without compensation.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </div>




</main>
  

  
</body>
```

Hello could someone tell me how should I put this blue box above red and the green one. Is there any way to put it like that? And should I use flexbox to do stuff like this or should I do it without flexbox? Here's an example of what I would like to have : http://prntscr.com/k8uuxa. (I hope you can post picture links here).

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but that's some basic css conditioning you're talking here. Perhaps you should consider properly learning it? You will need it, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
.flex-box .head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.flex-box {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And removed height from `.flexbox`

```css
body {
  background-color: olive;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#container {
  max-height: 1800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

a {
  background-color: chocolate;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#container>a:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#logout {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.bonus {
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/* nav is finally done after 1.5 hours lol and another 30mins  */

hr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.peepee {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.bees {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

.flex-box {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-box>div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
}

.flex-box .head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: green;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
}

li {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.head {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <img src=https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531870972494-627796a756dc?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=72a43beae93d56392f98f6eda2cdd8cb&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 width="100%" height="150" "border-radius:40px">
  <nav>
    <div id="main-content">
      <div id="container">
        <a id="main" href="main1.html">Main</a>
        <a id="information" class="bonus" href="information.html" style="background-color:#bad455">Statistics</a>
        <a id="contacts" class="bonus" href="contacts.html">Contacts</a>
        <a id="media" class="bonus" href="media.html">Media</a>
        <a id="logout" href="logout.html">Log out</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>



  <p class="peepee"> <img class="bees" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/46/Storni_1000128.JPG/1280px-Storni_1000128.JPG">More than 99 percent of all species, amounting to over five billion species,[7] that ever lived on Earth are estimated to
    be extinct.[8][9] Estimates on the number of Earth's current species range from 10 million to 14 million,[10] of which about 1.2 million have been documented and over 86 percent have not yet been described.[11] According to another study, the number
    of described species has been estimated at 1,899,587.[12] 2000–2009 saw approximately 17,000 species described per year.[12] The total number of undescribed organisms is unknown, but marine microbial species alone could number 20,000,000.[12] The
    number of quantified species will ipso facto always lag behind the number of described species, and species contained in these lists tend to be on the K side of the r/K selection continuum. More recently, in May 2016, scientists reported that 1 trillion
    species are estimated to be on Earth currently with only one-thousandth of one percent described.[13] The total amount of related DNA base pairs on Earth is estimated at 5.0 x 1037 and weighs 50 billion tonnes.[14] In comparison, the total mass of
    the biosphere has been estimated to be as much as 4 TtC (trillion [million million] tonnes of carbon).[15] In July 2016, scientists reported identifying a set of 355 genes from the Last Universal Common Ancestor (LUCA) of all organisms living on Earth.[16]</p>

  <hr>
  <div class="flex-box">
    <div class="head"></div>

    <div class="one">
      <h1>Pros</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Forest fires help to kill disease. </li>
        <li>It provides nutrients for new generations of growth. </li>
        <li>It refreshes the habitat zones. </li>
        <li>Low intensity fires don’t usually harm trees. </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <h1>Cons</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>A forest fire sets up the potential for soil erosion to occur. </li>
        <li>Forest fires always bring death in some form. </li>
        <li>Uncontrolled fires can cause localized air pollution. </li>
        <li>Homes can be destroyed without compensation.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>



  </main>



</body>
```